# How to get notified about error 500 using elastic beanstalk

Tags: amazon-web-services, elastic-beanstalk

I set up an application using elastic beanstalk and I would like to receive an email everytime an error 500 is caught containing the error message.

I'm able to receive an email using load balancer `HTTPCode_Backend_5XX` alarm in CloudWatch service but I don't get the error message so I can't dig through the error efficiently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We are handling these errors in a BaseController class directly in our application and send out the notification including all data we want (exception text, stacktrace, url that generated the exception, POST values, HTTP headers, etc.) using SNS to the developers (they love it... not ;)